# Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String' On getting all Products

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-web-api

```
  [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Get()
    {
        var GettingItemDetails = await db.wp_Posts.Join(db.wp_Postmeta,
            post => post.ID,
            meta => meta.post_id,
            (post, meta) => new { Post = post, Meta = meta })
            .Where(x => x.Post.ID > 0)
            .Where(x => x.Post.post_type == "product")
            .Where(x => x.Meta.meta_key == "_stock")
            .Select(x => new
            {
                Post_Title = x.Post.post_title,
                Meta_Key = x.Meta.meta_key,
                Meta_Value = x.Meta.meta_value,
                Product_Id = x.Post.ID,
            }
             ).ToListAsync();
        return Ok(GettingItemDetails);

        
    }
```

My Classes

```
public class wp_posts
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int post_author { get; set; } = 0;
    public DateTime post_date { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public DateTime post_date_gmt { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public string post_content { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string post_title { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string post_excerpt { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string post_status { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string comment_status { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string ping_status { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string post_password { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string post_name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string to_ping { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string pinged { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public DateTime post_modified { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public DateTime post_modified_gmt { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public string post_content_filtered { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int post_parent { get; set; } = 0;
    public string guid { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int menu_order { get; set; } = 0;
    public string post_type { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string post_mime_type { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int comment_count { get; set; } = 0;
    


}

 public class wp_postmeta
{
    [Key]
    public int meta_id { get; set; }
    public int post_id { get; set; } = 0;
    public string meta_key { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string meta_value { get; set; } = string.Empty;

   
}
```

Error i am Facing

ystem.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'.
at MySqlConnector.Core.Row.GetString(Int32 ordinal) in /*/src/MySqlConnector/Core/Row.cs:line 377
at MySqlConnector.MySqlDataReader.GetString(Int32 ordinal) in /*/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlDataReader.cs:line 287
at lambda_method13(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , ResultContext , SingleQueryResultCoordinator )
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at WoocommerceApi.Controllers.wp_postsController.Get() in D:\ApiDevelopment\WoocommerceApi\WoocommerceApi\Controllers\wp_postsController.cs:line 24
at lambda_method5(Closure , Object )
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Logged|12_1(ControllerActionInvoker invoker)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

All I want is to get product id and title from wp_posts and get stock qty from wp_postmeta
ID in wp_post and post_id in wp_postmeta are the same but still, I get this error if I pass a single id it works but I want all products

Comment: are you using entity framework?

Comment: This sound like a entity's property isn't nullable, but the associated column is.

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro, from the stack trace, I suppose it's EF Core.

Comment: Since you only have ints and strings, I think one or more int properties can be null in the database. Declare them as `int?`.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by Adding Nullable Type to my model Class

```
 public class wp_postmeta
{
    [Key]
    public int meta_id { get; set; }
    public int? post_id { get; set; } = 0;
    public string? meta_key { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string? meta_value { get; set; } = string.Empty;

   
}
```

Json Response is

```
 [
  {
    "post_Title": "Shirt",
    "meta_Key": "_stock",
    "meta_Value": "20",
    "product_Id": 12
  },
  {
    "post_Title": "Jeans",
    "meta_Key": "_stock",
    "meta_Value": null,
    "product_Id": 13
  }
]
```

Turns out meta value was null

Comment: This isn't a problem but be aware that `string?` [has a different meaning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) than non-reference types like `int?`.